# How do services like Flightradar24 and FlightAware track flights?

Tags: flightradar24, flight-tracking

Do they use the same data sources/aviation services? If so, how do they differ?

Comment: It really isn't in the scope of this site to evaluate outside services.

Comment: I'll answer anyway - flightradar has a network of receivers ( https://www.flightradar24.com/add-coverage ) to process transponder and Flarm signals

Comment: It cannot be closed for "opinion-based", as the main sources are well known (ANSP, private ADS-B receivers network). It may be broad though.

Comment: @mins, well it got closed for asking which one was better. (and anyway, personally I am not sure it is on topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.flightradar24.com/how-it-works - taken from the FR24 website. They use ADS-B - hence the reason the majority of General Aviation stuff doesn't show (unless it has a mode S transponder).